# Replace current quick disconnect barb with 5/16" barb

Tags: equipment, kegging, keg, corny-keg

I recently bought a length of hose for connecting my regulator to my quick disconnects. The hose fits snug on the regulator barb but is very loose on the quick disconnect barb.

Here is [the hose](http://www.compressedaircentre.com/product/5168mm-clear-braided-pvc-hose-030113008/) - 5/16" / 8mm ID.

And my [disconnect](http://www.thehomebrewcompany.ie/quick-disconnect-in-complete-new-grey-p-66.html).

I wanted to replace the current quick disconnect barb with a larger 5/16" one but I can't seem to find any Irish / UK / EU suppliers.

Are these what I'm looking for?

[5/16" Swivel Nut Set for MFL 1/4"](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/5-16-Swivel-Nut-Set-for-MFL-1-4-Ball-Lock-Kegging-Homebrew-World-Free-Shipping-/261552484346)

Or:

[Female Flare FFL Stainless Swivel Nut 1/4 to 5/16 Barb](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/Female-Flare-FFL-Stainless-Swivel-Nut-1-4-to-5-16-Barb-Adapter-Kegging-Homebrew-/130722409864?hash=item1e6fa9ad88:g:CbIAAOSwu4BVjBRI)

I don't know anything about the thread sizes on the disconnect. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They both look like they will work. I've never seen an MFL quick disconnect that isn't 1/4". I would opt for the one that states that the nut is chrome plated brass. Some FFL are 100% stainless steel, but they then need a washer to seal and that can be problematic.

If you can't buy the FFL locally an option is to use 1/4" hose and soak the end in boiling water before you push it onto the regulator barb. It's surprising you much hot vinyl hose will stretch.